# Dynamically hide/show columns in interactive report(Oracle APEX 5.1)

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I am developing an application which has a tree view and an interactive report. Based on the value selected in the tree node, i will refresh the report to show the node specific data.

Now, I want to hide some of the columns in the interactive report,for some tree node values. Is it possible to do it in APEX?
I am using Oracle APEX 5.1.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do this.Added  server side condition for those columns of interactive report that we want to hide based on the condition.

Everytime the report is refreshed the server side condition is executed.